# How do I store the output of my program in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster. I created a step for that cluster that runs the program "samplespark.py" (which is contained in an S3 bucket). samplespark.py creates a file and writes some output to that file, or at least it does when I test it on my computer. When I run samplespark.py on AWS EMR, I cannot find the output file.

How do I write an output file to an Amazon S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc)

You can pipe the result directly to S3 bucket as object.

$ python samplespark.py | mc pipe s3/myoutput/output.txt

Hope it helps.